# Building the ONLYOFFICE Editors front end

Tags: javascript, web, editor, onlyoffice

I am new in java-script and web projects, i am trying to start the Document editors and spreadsheet Editor on my browser from the ONLYOFFICE Open-source [Project](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/web-apps/tree/40e74224d4d4c529ebb8874bc7bc76fe3a66836a/apps).

i have got the error as in the image:
[image]

I have two questions:

**1** - It is Possible to run only the editors web-apps without the server?

**2** - if yes, how to build it, i tried that but i failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of searching I ended up with:
The ONLYOFFICE Editors works only with web server or with Docker. And in order to make it standalone it should make hard modification in the code or make a replacement to the services.

Answer (score 1):

The Document Editors cannot work without the server-side unfortunately. Our team built an ONLYOFFICE Desktop for that kind of purposes.

Comment: Oh my god, finally ONLYOFFICE Reply on my  question. So how can i use it on my PC without server, how to make a Server replacement or integrating like the ONLYOFFICE Desktop?

Comment: Dear Henka, it is not about integration, it is a software for local files editing - usual desktop Editors (well, not that usual, though))
Please find the link here: http://www.onlyoffice.com/apps.aspx

Comment: Can i install Server in my local network? on Windows 10, i tried but failed.